# pytesseract PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied in CreateProcess (Windows 10)

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Trying to make an OCR program that can extract the text from an image, convert it to bytes, and then have pytesseract convert it to string. I am encountering some permission errors. Here is my code right now. I cannot MRE this code, all of it is important.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

# Set the path to the tesseract executable
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Users\\hypro\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR"

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\hypro\Downloads\image1.jpg')
#Alternatively: can be skipped if you have a Blackwhite image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray, img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(img_bin)
kernel = np.ones((2, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
# Encode the image as a JPEG
_, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
print(encoded_image)
# Convert the encoded image to a string
image_bytes = encoded_image.tobytes()
out_below = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print("OUTPUT:", out_below)
```

I tried checking if the directory is correct: it is. I have permission to execute tesseract.exe, and permission to view it. Here is my full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hypro\ocr2.py", line 21, in <module>
    out_below = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hypro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
           ^
  File "C:\Users\hypro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>  
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hypro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hypro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hypro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\hypro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1493, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: did you debug your program? how did you do that? what did you learn? did you tell pytesseract where to find the tesseract executable? [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: From my last program, I just switched IDEs. I used ChatGPT to help me debug. And I accidentally pasted the wrong code. My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that you have the correct path to the tesseract executable?

Acording to [pytesseract docs](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), the executable path should be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract`

In your case, you might need to do

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Users\\hypro\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract"
```

Comment: I did this but with tesseract.exe at the end, and it worked! Thank you!